# How to check for PIA 2007 installed?

Tags: .net, wix

How to check for PIA 2007 installed using wix installer condition?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The recommended approach is to check system registry or certain file on disk. As far as I can see, PIA 2007 installs lots of stuff, and populates the registry heavily. So, if you need a particular component to be present, check for its value in registry or its files on disk.

I would recommend downloading [PIA 2007](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=18346), extract the MSI file and open it with [Orca](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370557.aspx). Then examine the Registry table to know what gets written and where, or the File/Directory tables, to find out where the interesting files are installed.